# If there exists a surjection $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow A$, then $A$ is countable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, set-theory

I ran into a question, which is asking us to show that if we find a surjection from the naturals to any set $A$, then it is sufficient to say it's countable. I thought of the following proof, and I want to know if my solution is correct or not, and if not then why.

Keep in mind that the definition of countable used here is any finite set or denumerable set.

---

*My attempt:*

Suppose there exists a surjection $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow A$. If it is injective, then $f$ is a bijection and by defintion, $A$ is countable.

Now suppose $f$ is not injective. This means there exists two elements $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $\mathbb{N}$ that aren't equal, but have equal images under $f$. I will define a new term here, called a "repeat of $r \in A$", to be any term $x_n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there exists $x_m \neq x_n$ where $f(x_n) = f(x_m) = r$. (I'm really terrible at names.)

Let $A = \{a_i: i \in \Delta\}$, and suppose $A_j$ is the set of repeats of $a_j$, where $a_j \in A$ **with the exception of a single repeat**. This means there exists a unique element, say $u \in \mathbb{N} - A_j$ such that $f(u) = a_j$. This means for every element $a$ in $A$, there exists unique element $r$ inside the set $\mathbb{N} - \bigcup_{i \in \Delta}A_i$ such that $f(r) = a$.

So by defining the function $g:\mathbb{N} - \bigcup_{i \in \Delta}A_i \rightarrow A$ by $g(x) = f(x)$, $g$ is a bijection.

Case 1: $\mathbb{N} - \bigcup_{i \in \Delta}A_i$ is finite. Then there exists a bijection $h:\mathbb{N} - \bigcup_{i \in \Delta}A_i \rightarrow \mathbb{N}_k$ where $k \in \mathbb{N}$. So $h \circ g^{-1}$ is a bijection, so A is finite (meaning it is countable).

Case 2: $\mathbb{N} - \bigcup_{i \in \Delta}A_i$ is infinite. Since $\mathbb{N} - \bigcup_{i \in \Delta}A_i \subset \mathbb{N}$ and any subset of a countable set is countable, then $\mathbb{N} - \bigcup_{i \in \Delta}A_i$ is denumerable so there exists a bijection $h: \mathbb{N} - \bigcup_{i \in \Delta}A_i \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. So $h \circ g^{-1}$ is a bijection, implying $A$ is countable.

In all cases, $A$ is countable. QED.

---

Thank you, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The reasoning looks fine but can be streamlined.

Since $f$ is surjective there exists for each $a \in A$ some $n_a \in \mathbb N$ with $f(n_a)=a$.

Define $N = \{n_a: a \in A\}$.

The function $g: N \to A$ is bijective by construction.

Hence $|N| = |A|$.

Since $N \subset \mathbb N$ we have $|N| \le |\mathbb N|$ and so $A$ is either finite or countable.

---

**Note:** The notation $A = \{a_i: i \in \Delta\}$ doesn't save any ink. It just moves the names of the elements. You might as well just write $A = \{a: a \in A \}$.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is unclear.

- What is $\Delta$? It isn't defined.
- Do you define the set $A$, which is given?
- The definition of $A_j$ isn't precise. You have to precisely define which elements belong to the set and which doesn't. Which one is the exeptional repeat that belongs to the set? Maybe you try to use axiom of choice, but it isn't clear.

You could change the proof a bit. Just define $$N_\mathrm{rep} = \{n\in\Bbb N\:|\: f(m) = f(n)\text{ for some }m<n\},\quad N_\mathrm{unique}=\Bbb N\setminus N_\mathrm{rep}$$ and show that $f|_{N_\mathrm{unique}}$ is a bijection.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists a surjection, by definition $|A|\leq|\mathbb{N}|$ which is, in my opinion, sufficient to prove the fact that $A$ is countable. Otherwise, if $f$ is a surjection, $\forall y\in A, \exists x\in\mathbb{N}|f(x)=y $. Thus it is sufficient to define $N_y=\{y\in A|x,x'\in \mathbb{N}, y=f(x)=f(x')\}$. Then $$f: \mathbb{N}/\bigcup_{y\in A}N_y\rightarrow A$$ is by definition a bijection, and $\mathbb{N}/\bigcup_{y\in A}N_y\subseteq\mathbb{N}$. Here $\mathbb{N}/\bigcup_{y\in A}N_y$ is the quotient by $\bigcup_{y\in A}N_y$.